# SharePoint 2010 - Content type in key filters not arranged alphabetically

Tags: managed-metadata, key-filter

I am using Content type in Key Filters (Metadata navigation) to filter out our content.  The Content type drop down is not arrnaged alphabetically.  Is there a way to accomplish this i.e arrange the content type alphabetically?

Thanks,
Ricky

Answer (score 1):

Go to list settings and select Change new button order and default content type.

It might help, I am not sure if there is any other way.

Comment: The problem is that we are not using all the content types in the library in the "New" button, so we want all the content types to be displayed alphabetically but only some of them are used in the library...which makes this complicated.  I tried arranging the order and then taking out checkmarks for the one we are not using but it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: If you could put javascript on page, http://sebastienayotte.wordpress.com/2009/08/04/sorting-drop-down-list-with-jquery/ may help

Comment: not aware of any other option.